# How can I start remote debugging on a samsung galaxy tablet?

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I have a web app that I need to tweak for Chrome on a tablet. I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab for testing. I'm trying to follow [these](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) famous instructions to use developer tools with Chrome for Android. I have downloaded and installed the Samsung USB driver from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows), and it has sprayed 25 folders in C:\Program Files\SAMSUNG\USB Drivers. If there are further steps to identify and use the drivers in these folders, I haven't followed them.

My problem is that chrome:inspect is not finding my device. The device manager shows the device properly installed, but the driver tab says it's running a microsoft driver from 2006! All attempts to update the driver finish with "The best driver is already installed." I can browse the device in Windows explorer. What am I missing?

Chrome on my desktop: Version 36.0.1942.0 canary
Chrome on device: Version 34.0.1847.114
Galaxy Tab: GT-P7510
Android Version: 4.0.4

[image: Why does my 2014 galaxy tab have a 2006 driver]

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Make sure that your chrome versions are the newest, please add your chrome versions (desktop & android device), as well as android version to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me (developing on windows 8, samsung S4 connected via USB ) chrome://inspect works, but only if I have adb running in the background. This was not mentioned in the documentation last time I checked.

Get [android platform tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) if you don't already have it. Then, from a command prompt in android-sdk/platform-tools > adb start-server.

You can do this as often as you like, and may need to do it every time you reconnect your phone, or wake your machine.